# decltype(auto) in function return type does not deduces const types

Tags: c++

In following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct TD;

decltype(auto) getMyConst() {
    const int val = 10;
    return (const int)val; // const int cast is not needed here actually
}

int main()
{
    
    TD<decltype(getMyConst())> type_test;
}
```

produces error:

```
main.cpp:41:32: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<int>'
TD<decltype(getMyConst())> type_test;
```

which indicates that deduced type is `int`, I would expect decltype rules to deduce `const int`. Why does clang compiler deduce 'int'?

Comment: Top-level const qualifiers on the function return type are ignored. `const int f();` and `int f();` declare the same function. You'll see the same outcome with just plain `const int getMyConst()` ; this has nothing to do with `decltype(auto)`

Comment: Additionally, prvalues of non-class, non-array types [automatically lose cv-qualifiers](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-2): `(const int)val` isn't `const` to begin with.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, so top level const on function return type will not get removed for object types. Actually I checked it with my example (changed int to std::string).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Interestingly, `const` is a part of the type in this case, so it's stripped when you call the function, not when you declare it. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b4K5K3

Comment: I see the answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype#Semantics: - .... "prvalues of non-class types always have cv-unqualified types, despite the statically declared different type."